# Is there any Free Ide for Groovy/Grails development

Tags: grails, groovy, ide

Is there any good IDE for Groovy and Grail development

As IntelliJ IDEA is not (free) but pretty good. . any other IDE which provide equivalent features,but is not paid.

I searched for answers but every where suggestions were 2 years or older. .
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233664/best-ide-for-grails-groovy)

As 2 year is a lot of time situation might change Just want to know which IDE is best NOW. .

============

## EDIT :UPDATE

after reading responses I am finally going with Spring Source Tool (STS)

Comment: Well, IDE-wise there are the three major players Netbeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ. Here is a setup for Netbeans: http://www.grails.org/NetBeans+Integration - You can find a Eclipse plugin on its own marketplace. In the end its mostly a matter of preference. Therefore, it is unlikely that you will get any helpful answers on this question, you should rather try for yourself. I would for example rather pay for IntelliJ than switch. In fact, I do. Its not that expensive.

Comment: If some one did not liked question I am sorry ,I searched but responses every where,but they were years old. .so asked for suggestion on a public platform to know which option will be best in current scenario. .

Comment: This is my opinion from experience - IntelliJ is hands down the best out there. It is worth double or triple what it costs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide) are some of the IDE who support Grails.

- **IntelliJ IDEA**:
  Only the Ultimate edition support Grails natively. With the Free edition you can use Grails but you will miss out on all the Grails specific features like automatic classpath management, GSP editor and quick access to Grails commands.
- **NetBeans**:
  NetBeans provides a Groovy/Grails plugin that automatically recognizes Grails projects and provides the ability to run Grails applications in the IDE, code completion and integration with the Glassfish server.
- **Eclipse**:
  We recommend that users of Eclipse looking to develop Grails application take a look at Groovy/Grails Tool Suite, which offers built in support for Grails including automatic classpath management, a GSP editor and quick access to Grails commands.

See the website for more information about how to install on you chosen IDE.

Comment: thanks for categorical response :)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse for instance [Groovy - IDE support](http://groovy.codehaus.org/IDE+Support)

Or the [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SPRING TOOL SUITE](http://www.springsource.org/sts) which provides the best Eclipse-powered development environment

Check [STS integration](http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration) for grails